# Update emacs after changing init settings

Tags: init-file

Is it possible to update emacs after changing my init settings without having to fire another session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Use the commands `eval-last-sexp` (`C-x C-e`) and/or `eval-buffer`.

Comment: Would like to have a function that I can call in my init file that updates the session for any changes.

Comment: That’s what `eval-buffer` does.

Comment: Well, that’s what `eval-buffer` does when you use it to evaluate your init file. Obviously if you evaluated some other buffer then the results would not be the same as restarting Emacs.

Comment: Thus what I have to do is hit `M-x eval-buffer` upon the buffer I change?

Comment: That’s correct.

Comment: Does the evaluation cascade to other files?  For instance, if I do `M-x eval-buffer` on `.emacs` would the command evaluate changes to other mode set by `.emacs`?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: `M-x eval-buffer` evaluates all of the code in the buffer.  It's *not* the same thing as "refreshing your entire config" because an Emacs config is a software program, and whether running a program twice is the same thing as running it once depends on the program.  So there is no "refresh config" command, because it's not possible to have one of those.  What `M-x eval-buffer` does depends on the lisp code in the buffer in question, and the current state of Emacs.  So your question doesn't have a trivial answer.

Comment: Example: `(load "foo")` reads and evaluates library `foo.el` while  `(require 'foo)` reads and evaluates `foo.el` *if and only if it hasn't already happened*.  Evaluating the `require` version twice does not, therefore, cause `foo.el` to be loaded twice.

Comment: While you are technically correct, for most things that people do while editing their init files simply calling `eval-buffer` is sufficient to avoid restarting Emacs.